# Reference another file in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Basically I have a solution which is having 2 projects.

1. Main Website
2. Console Application which will be used to schedule Jobs.

My problem here is the both the projects are using a XML file which have lots of configuration. The developers are updating the file in the main project but not in the Console App.

So is there any way to include the XML file in the main project into the debug/release folders of the console application directly. So that, when they get the latest of console app, it can pickup the file from the referenced location that is in the main project. Hope I am making sense..!

-Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to `Specify the File Add Option`, add config file in Main Project and to add `another file` `but by linking` on the first.

Every change on first is reflected on second file.

link : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234

Answer (score 0):

You want to just have once copy of the XML file checked into TFS.
Then, add that one XML file to both website project and the console application projects. Set the properties of the XML file to Content - Always copy.

Something like this would work...

```
/root
   /Website
    website.csproj

   /Console
    console.csproj

   /Config
    MyConfigFile.xml
```

In both the website.csproj and the console.csproj you would have an entry like this...

```
<Content Include="..\Config\MyConfigFile.xml">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```